# Isomorphism between a principal bundle and a pullback bundle.

Tags: principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

I have seen in many texts on the classification of main bundles that, given two homotopically equivalent X and Y spaces, this equivalence being the function $f: Y \rightarrow X$, given a group G, if $k_{G}(X), k_{G}(Y)$ represents the set of isomorphism classes of principal G-bundles over $X$ and $Y$ respectively, there is a bijection between them. But this means that, given a principal G-bundle equivalence class of X, say $[(P, X, G, \pi)]$, there is only one corresponding to it, say $[(E, Y, G, \rho)]$, and we would have for $(P, X, G, \pi)$ the corresponding $(f^*P, Y, G, \sigma)$.

My question is whether the principal G-bundles $(P, X, G, \pi)$ and $(f^*P, Y, G, \sigma)$ are isomorphic as the principal G-bundles.

Appreciate.

Comment: Did you mean to ask if $(E, Y, G, \rho)$ and $(f^*P, Y, G, \sigma)$ are isomorphic?

Comment: No. I want to know if $(P, X, G, \pi)$ and $(f^* P, Y, G, \rho)$ are isomorphic if the spaces X and Y are homotopically equivalent and $f$ is the equivalence. I am in doubt because to explain the "magnetic monopole", most authors say that $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ and $(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{worldline\})\times \mathbb{R}$ are homotopically equivalent so the bundles are respective are isomorphic. And I thought it was a good chance that this "respective" would be the pullback.

Comment: Do you mean an isomorphism covering $f$?

Comment: Isomorphism in the sense of principal G-bundles: is there an invertible and G-equivariant map $\phi: P \rightarrow f^* P$?For example, if f were a diffeomorphism it would be $\phi(p) = (p, \phi^{-1}(\pi(p)))$.

Comment: Note that $P$ and $f^*P$ are $G$-bundles on different spaces. An isomorphism of $G$-bundles implies that the two spaces are diffeomorphic.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question then? If so, I will edit my answer below to explain this.

Comment: Answer me, I believe we can understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a paracompact space, then $k_G(X) = [X, BG]$ where $BG$ is the classifying space of the topological group $G$ and the brackets denote the collection of homotopy classes of maps $X \to BG$. If $f : Y \to X$ is a continuous map, then there is an induced map $[X, BG] \to [Y, BG]$ given by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha\circ f$. If $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to a paracompact space, we can view this as a map $k_G(X) \to k_G(Y)$ which, by construction of the identification $k_G(X) = [X, BG]$, is precisely $f^*$, i.e. the map $k_G(X) \to k_G(Y)$ is given by $[P] \mapsto [f^*P]$. Now, if $f$ is a homotopy equivalence, then $f^*$ is a bijection (if $g$ is a homotopy inverse of $f$, then $g^*$ is an inverse of $f^*$).

In conclusion, if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent to paracompact spaces, and $f : Y \to X$ is a homotopy equivalence, then $f^* : k_G(X) \to k_G(Y)$ given by $[P] \mapsto [f^*P]$ is a bijection.